# expansion variable inside a single double quote string

Tags: bash, zsh

I need to expand a variable value inside an string.

The problem is that this string is single quoted and enclose a double quoted string:

```
checksum256=$sha256sum $filename
curl -X POST \
  'http://localhost:8080/documents?application=RDOCUI&user=nif' \
  -F docFile=@/home/jeusdi/projects/repositori-digital/stress/randomfile4b7f12a2-2cb0-49e3-b02b-1ededaa281e5.txt \
  -F 'docAttributes={
   "confidential":"N",
   "transactionId": "sdf",
   "codiDirCorp": "CorpCode",
   "expiration": "10/10/2025",
   "description": "desc",
   "locked": "N",
   "title": "titol",
   "docHash": "${checksum256}"  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< THE PROBLEM IS HERE
}'
```

`checksum256` is not expanded.

Take care that this expansion is inside a single quoted string and at the same time inside a double-quoted string:

```
'"$expansion"'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is a bit like "how can I drive to the airport without using a vehicle?". The whole point of having single quoted strings is to **not** having expansion, so why are you using single quotes if you don't want it? Also, I don't see in your concrete example, that `$checksum256`would be surrounded by single quotes, as there is no stray single quote in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single quotes. The double quotes inside the single quotes are just part of the value, like an `a` or a `1`. They don't tell the shell to expand the quote, because they aren't *shell* quotes.

Either use double quotes to quote the entire string, escaping the literal quotes inside:

```
-F "docAttributes={...,\"docHash\": \"$checksum256\" ...}"
```

Or better  yet, use `jq` to safely generate the JSON value for you. (The above can fail if the value of `checksum256` itself contains double-quotes.)

```
attrs=$(jq -n --arg ck "$checksum256" '{confidential: "N", ..., docHash: $k}')
curl -X POST ... -F "docAttributes=$attrs"
```